# Compute Triple integral for each "R" > 0

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral, bounds-of-integration

Compute for each $R >0$ the following: 
$$ 
\int\int\int (x^2 + y^2+z) dV\;\text{ over the region: }\;x^2 + y^2+z^2 ≤ 2Rz
$$
I decided to use polar:

Starting with $R=1$

rearranging the region I get a new region $x^2 + y^2+ (z-1)^2 ≤ 1 $ the sphere centered at $(0,0,1)$

Then I set up the integral
$$
\int_{\theta=}^{\theta=}\int_{r=}^{r=}\int_{z=}^{z=}r^3+rz \,dzdrd\theta.
$$

This is how far I got, I do not know how to define the bounds or whether this is the correct approach. Also after computing this integral for R=1 how do I find the general answer for $R > 0$ ?

Answer (score 3):

That region is$$\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3\mid x^2+y^2+(z-R)^2=R^2\}.$$A first change of coordinates could be $x\mapsto X$, $y\mapsto Y$, and $z\mapsto Z+R$. Then your function becomes$$(X,Y,Z)\mapsto X^2+Y^2+Z+R.$$If you compute the integral of this function on the sphere centered at $(0,0,0)$ with radius $R$, you will get$$\int_0^R\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\rho^2\sin(\varphi)\bigl(\rho^2\sin^2(\varphi)+\rho\cos(\varphi)+R\bigr)\,\mathrm d\varphi\,\mathrm d\theta\,\mathrm dr=\frac4{15}\pi R^4(2R+5).$$

Comment: I do not understand the $Z-R$ part in $\mapsto X^2+Y^2+Z-R.$ if $z$ becomes $Z+R$ then we would get $Z^2$ and the region becomes $(X,Y,Z)\mapsto X^2+Y^2+Z^2 =R^2$ I would think.. and is it ok to use the polar coordinates like I set up?

Comment: ok I understand now

Comment: But the function that you are integrating is $x^2+y^2+z$. It has no $z^2$.

Comment: I was confusing the region and function

Comment: now I am wondering if $z becomes Z+R $ then why did you say the function becomes $X^2+Y^2+Z−R$ subtracting $R$? should we not add it?

Comment: Right. I shall edit my answer.